# i have an issue with my laravel 5 project i can't find the way to run my project on my local machine

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

127.0.0.1:8000>
[Fri Sep 24 10:46:12 2021] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ErrorException: file_put_contents(/var/www/html/mpm/storage/framework/views/9573eb5dc606d0d2f327fdda9ed9d4ecfd5f1e97.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\amit\mpmnew\mpm20sept2021\mpm\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem.php:122

this is my error can any one help me with this.

Comment: Clear your cache

Comment: execute artisan command `cache clear` `config clear`

Comment: That looks strange. Why does your application try to write to `/var/www` on a Windows system?

Comment: just a tip: XAMPP might not be the best option for running a Laravel application. There are better options like `php artisan serve`. On windows there is no /var/www/. have you copied your whole application including the cache folders?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:cache
```

You can programmatically execute the command by adding the following to your routes:

```
Route::get('/clear-cache', function() {
    $exitCode = Artisan::call('cache:clear');
    $exitCode = Artisan::call('config:cache');
    return 'DONE'; //Return anything
});
```